# What should I type in migration if I want to multiply 2 values from two different tables ? ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework

Tags: sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

This is what am I suppose to complete "Calculate total animal maintenance cost. Which is obtained by adding the food cost (food cost * animal weight), housing cost." I don't know how to do calculation for all (PetWeight from PetRescued Table)*(FoodCost from PetSpecies Table) and Insert it into my MaintenanceCost Table.

**And**

For example, I have 4 type of pet species which is Cat,Dog,Rabbit and Rodent. The HousingCost for the pets are 10,20,30,40.This is Table 1. For Table 2 which is the PetRescued, How do I calculate the sum of HousingCost for how many cats/dogs/.../... that I have in my PetRescued database and Insert it into my MaintenanceCost Table.

**This is my PetRescued entity which is also one of the Table**

```
public class PetRescued
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string PetName { get; set; }
    public int PetAge { get; set; }
    public string PetGender { get; set; }
    public double PetWeight { get; set; }
    public DateTime? DateWhenRescued { get; set; }
    public string PetBreedName { get; set; }    

    public PetSpecies PetSpecies { get; set; }
    public byte PetSpeciesId { get; set; }

    public PetSanctuary PetSanctuary { get; set; }
    public byte PetSanctuaryId { get; set; }    
}
```

**This is my PetSpecies entity which consist of the FoodCost and also my second Table**

```
 public class PetSpecies
{
    public byte Id { get; set; }


    public string SpeciesName { get; set; }
    public double FoodCost { get; set; }
    public double HousingCost { get; set; } 
}
```

**This is my MaintenanceCost entity which is use to store the result from the calculation**

```
public class MaintenanceCost
{
    public byte Id { get; set; }

    public double TotalFoodCost { get; set; }
    public double TotalHousingCost { get; set; }
    public double TotalVetBillCost { get; set; }    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query you need is something like this. It inserts one entity containing sum of all costs.

```
INSERT INTO MaintenanceCost (TotalFoodCost,TotalHousingCost,TotalVetBillCost)
Values (
(SELECT SUM(PetRescued.PetWeight * PetSpecies.FoodCost FROM PetRescued INNER JOIN PetSpecies ON PetRescued.PetSpeciesId = PetSpecies.Id)),
(SELECT SUM(PetSpecies.HousingCost FROM PetRescued INNER JOIN PetSpecies ON PetRescued.PetSpeciesId = PetSpecies.Id)),
"the amount of TotalVetBillCost"
)
```

However this approach is against one the basic rules of databases that is never store a data that can be retrieved from other data stored in the database. Also, It is clear that when the data in other two tables alter, this entity will no longer be valid.